# "$A$ is a ring with zero ideal  the product of a finite number of maximal ideals . Then $A$ is Noetherian if and only if $A$ is Artinian."

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

"Let $A$ be a ring in which the zero ideal is the product of the maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_i, \, i=1, \cdots, r$. Then $A$ is Noetherian if and only if $A$
is Artinian."

This is Corollary 6.11, p. 78 from Atiyah and McDonald's "Introduction to Commutative
Algebra". Their proof is quite elegant. I would like to share my approach for the proof,
and some phenomenon that arises there.

Suppose that $A$ is Noetherian. I will show that $A$ is Artinian. So take a decreasing
sequence of ideals $\alpha_0 \supset \alpha_1 \supset \cdots$. Adding to each term of
the sequence the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_i$, we obtain a new decreasing sequence of
ideals of $A$ given by $\alpha_0 + \mathfrak{m}_i \supset \alpha_1 + \mathfrak{m}_i \supset \cdots$. Now take the image of this sequence under the canonical map $A \rightarrow A / \mathfrak{m}_i$ to obtain a decreasing sequence of $A$-submodules of the $A$-module
$A /\mathfrak{m}_i$ given by 
$\frac{\alpha_0 + \mathfrak{m}_i}{\mathfrak{m}_i} \supset \frac{\alpha_1 + \mathfrak{m}_i}
{\mathfrak{m}_i} \supset \cdots$. But $A /\mathfrak{m}_i$ is also a vector space over itself
and since $A$ is Noetherian so will be $A /\mathfrak{m}_i$. But for vector spaces Noetherian and Artinian are equivalent notions, thus the decreasing sequence 
$\frac{\alpha_0 + \mathfrak{m}_i}{\mathfrak{m}_i} \supset \frac{\alpha_1 + \mathfrak{m}_i}
{\mathfrak{m}_i} \supset \cdots$ must terminate, i.e. there exists some $N_i$ s.t.
$\alpha_{N_i} - \alpha_{N_i + k} \subseteq \mathfrak{m}_i$ for any positive integer $k$.
Repeating the same argument for all $i=1,\cdots,r$ and setting $N=\max_{i}\left\{N_i \right\}$ we have that $\alpha_{N} - \alpha_{N + k} \subseteq \prod_{i=1}^r \mathfrak{m}_i=0$ and 
so $\alpha_N=0$. Thus the initial sequence for $A$ must terminate and so $A$ is Artinian.

My question is twofold: 1) is the above argument technically correct? 2) If yes, how do we interpret the fact that the sequence terminates at the zero ideal?

Comment: Is $\alpha_{N} = 0$ the only possible conclusion?

Comment: @ChrisLeary: I think so.

Comment: @Manos-How about $\alpha_{N} = \alpha_{N+k}$ for all $k$?

Comment: @ChrisLeary: How can you prove that?

Comment: @Manos-Their difference is $0$.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: I see. I was interpreting this erroneously. Thanks. If you can post this as an answer i will accept it.